# Changing ranges in timeline

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, timeline

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68386624/plot-timeline-in-python) I would like to change the X range (date), so that it will be from 1970, 1980,... till 2020 and the events will be a..b, etc... (I have a predefined list of events). I use the following code which dates starts with 1969 and ends with 1970 (instead of 1970 and 2020 respectively). The tried 2 options:
'event': ['a', 'b','c','d','e','f'],
first option:

```
'date':pd.date_range(start='1970', periods=6)
```

second option:

```
'date': ['1970', '1980','1990','2000','2010','2020']
```

Here is the complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'event': ['a', 'b','c','d','e','f'],
       'date': ['1970','1980','1990','2000','2010','2020']
     # ->   'date':pd.date_range(start='1970', periods=6)
             
    }
)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

levels = np.tile(
    [-5, 5, -3, 3, -1, 1],
    int(np.ceil(len(df)/6))
)[:len(df)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12.8, 4), constrained_layout=True);
ax.set(title="A series of events")

ax.vlines(df['date'], 0, levels, color="tab:red");  # The vertical stems.
ax.plot(   # Baseline and markers on it.
    df['date'],
    np.zeros_like(df['date']),
    "-o",
    color="k",
    markerfacecolor="w"
);

# annotate lines
for d, l, r in zip(df['date'], levels, df['event']):
    ax.annotate(
        r,
        xy=(d, l),
        xytext=(-3, np.sign(l)*3),
        textcoords="offset points",
        horizontalalignment="right",
        verticalalignment="bottom" if l > 0 else "top"
    );

# format xaxis with 4 month intervals
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=4));
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%b %Y"));
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, ha="right");

# remove y axis and spines
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False);
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False);
ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)    
ax.margins(y=0.1);
plt.show();
```

As explained above I would like to see on Xais only years 1970 to 2020 (with no month and day) and respectively their events (a to f).

Comment: Set ```df['date']``` or a new var ```df['year']```  ```= df['date'].dt.year``` and that will only give years as X axis

Comment: Thanks! @SurajShourie, I used df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.year However, I get in the graph only one date Jul 1975

Comment: it is because you are setting the major locator 
remove these lines: 
```ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=4));
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%b %Y"));```

Comment: @SurajShourie, Sorry I get errors. I'll be glad, if you can present all the relevant lines and get the required result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer based on comments and from what I've understood, see full code below (notice I have just added one line for `year` and commented out the `xaxis` part):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'event': ['a', 'b','c','d','e','f'],
       'date': ['1970','1980','1990','2000','2010','2020']
     # ->   'date':pd.date_range(start='1970', periods=6)
             
    }
)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.year # ADDED THIS!

levels = np.tile(
    [-5, 5, -3, 3, -1, 1],
    int(np.ceil(len(df)/6))
)[:len(df)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12.8, 4), constrained_layout=True);
ax.set(title="A series of events")

ax.vlines(df['date'], 0, levels, color="tab:red");  # The vertical stems.
ax.plot(   # Baseline and markers on it.
    df['date'],
    np.zeros_like(df['date']),
    "-o",
    color="k",
    markerfacecolor="w"
);

# annotate lines
for d, l, r in zip(df['date'], levels, df['event']):
    ax.annotate(
        r,
        xy=(d, l),
        xytext=(-3, np.sign(l)*3),
        textcoords="offset points",
        horizontalalignment="right",
        verticalalignment="bottom" if l > 0 else "top"
    );

# COMMENTED OUT THIS!
# format xaxis with 4 month intervals
# ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=4));
# ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%b %Y"));
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, ha="right");

# remove y axis and spines
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False);
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False);
ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)    
ax.margins(y=0.1);
plt.show();
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

Comment: Looks great. Is there a way to create automatically the same correct range (as seen): 1970 to 2020 (with 10Y gap)? In addition, it is great that there is no frame around the graph! Why it was added to the source I sent before?

Comment: Ideally, create a new question (after accepting this one) for follow-ups. But regarding your range just use ```pd.date_range```